# mysql query, reuse columnnames in query

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql query, something like this:

```sql
SELECT users*100 as totalusers, totalusers*90 AS totalsalerys FROM table
```

As you can see I want to reuse the `totalusers` when calculating `totalsalerys` so I son't have to write the same code again. That dosen't seem to work in mysql, is there another easy way to do this?

My query is just an example, change the `*100` and `*90` to some very long formula and you might see what i mean..

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  (@r := users * 100) as totalusers,
        @r * 90 AS totalsalerys
FROM    table
```

You can also use a subquery as `@Tom Ritter` advices, but it's not friendly to `ORDER BY ... LIMIT ...` clause.

In `MySQL`, all results of the inner subquery will be fetched **before** applying any filters in the outer subquery.

Comment: how about using sum or count on users field? as it  would be applied on each row separately? just a thaught

Answer (score 1):

I believe you would have to copy/paste the formula or use a subquery.  The below would work in T-SQL, but I imagine it'd work in MySQL as well since it's pretty simple.

```
 SELECT 
     x.totalusers, x.totalusers*90 AS totalsalerys 
 FROM (
      SELECT users*100 as totalusers FROM table
 ) x
```